# Louvre Trip Planning for multi-day visit

Tags: tips-and-tricks, paris, museums, the-louvre

I am planning a first-time trip to the Louvre for this month and have allotted 4 days because of its size.

1. On what days is the Museum the least busy? Are there any days with cheaper tickets?
2. Can I leave the museum for lunch and regain entry for the afternoon?
3. What sort of items am I allowed and not allowed to bring in to the museum (that I may find useful? eg. Folding chairs/stools, water bottles, snacks, bags with clothing layers to make myself comfortable temperature wise, selfie sticks)
4. Are there other good techniques to minimize waiting:

[avoid using main entrance](http://www.landingstanding.com/secret-entrance-to-the-louvre/)

[buy tickets online](http://www.louvre.fr/en/buy-tickets)

@MTS: gratitude for helping to reframe the question

Comment: 1/2 seem like perfectly valid, on topic questions (although shows something of a lack of research).
3 and 4 feels pretty full on opinion based, and like asking people for their own anecdotes of visiting the museum. Useful, but makes for a horrible mess on a voted Q/A like this site.

Comment: What does "best practices" with regards to buying tickets even mean? Adding in extra linking words doesn't help mine and pnuts confusion. Sureluy the only practice for a ticket is: 1. Buy it 2. Show it to gain admittance?

Comment: Thanks for editing but note that how broad a question is is only to some extent up to the asker, but also determined [by our site rules and guidance](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You are trying to override those and that is what you are getting -1s and comments for instead of answers, even though your question is good IMHO (I gave you a +1). Why don't you edit your question again, e.g. do some own research so you can figure out the answer to 1) yourself (in case ask whether it's really the best option for you), 2) is fine, and be much more precise on 3)+4) or drop it.

Comment: If you decide to leave your question as is, I would find it justified to close it for being too broad, too much about opinions and lack of research on the first part of your Q.

Comment: @mts thanks for the feedback.  I have added clarifying exampel for Q3 and Q4.  Do the examples constrain the questions enough?  Our experience with lessons-learned and pitfalls may be very different and hence the differing views.  With regard to the research, I have researched but did not feel the need to publish my findings.  I am fishing for genuine experience (not documented in the web, because I can Google that myself quicker).

Comment: You seem to be asking, in parts 3/4 for many people to come forward with their experiences. While that can work well for a review site (seriously, go look at TripADvisor review for the Louvre, it may help you), it doesn't work well here, where we want definitive answers (there can be more than one) with the best being voted to the top. We don't want a long list of similar answers - that's exactly the kind of website StackExchange was set up to avoid.

Comment: @gatorback do you mind if I propose an edit to your Q that should make it  fit for this site? besides what has been said about tripadvisor etc vs this site absolutely holds

Comment: @mts: please propose.  I appreciate the constructive offer.  My thoughts:   The questions do not ask to review the Louvre but is an all-hands call to share relevant decision making facts (valuable because gained through experience) and provide a line of reasoning of why they are relevant /helpful /constructive.  The questions are broad / open-ended so as to not exclude any potentially useful decision support fact

Comment: Just go to the Musée D'orsay  instead  :/   the Louvre is just *so* crowded...

Comment: An interesting question would be, factually, what days (that is to say - of the calendar year) are the least busy at the Louvre?

Comment: @JoeBlow: thanks for the good constructive comments.  Prompted me to add that my trip is at the end of this month.

Comment: [No eating or drinking in the galleries, no running, no touching, no raising your voice, no smoking](http://www.louvre.fr/en/how-use-louvre/showing-respect-collections#tabs). Photography is allowed in the permanent exhibits, but no flash, tripod, other setups.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: The Louvre is one of the most popular museum in the world, so there will be tons of people every day and every hours; just be patient, and if you miss something, don't worry, come back to it next time you are in Paris.

Don't go on Mondays, even if the museum is open, other Museums (municipal museums, like the Musée d'Orsay) in Paris are closed on Mondays so everyone divert to the Louvre.

Try to get there as early as possible (opening) or just at lunch time when tour groups leave for lunch and use alternate entry points (other than the pyramid).

I never went in the evening, but it can be fun (Wednesday and Friday).

I think it is allowed to leave at mid-day for lunch and come back later on (a quick google says it is allowed, but always ask on site, just in case).

Chairs are probably (surely) not allowed; selfie sticks are maybe still allowed, but I would not bring one; there are just too many people to safely use it. (leave it at home). There are exceptions for people who sit down and copy arts, but you need a copyist card from the Louvre).

For the visit, I would leave all non-essential stuff at the the hotel/apartment, that includes backpacks, umbrellas, extra clothing... just bring the minimum with you  (ids, money, camera/phone).

There is a cloakroom under the pyramid if you need to stash your bags if you cannot be without them.

Wear comfortable shoes and light attire, it can be hot during the day, there is not much ventilation in the museum.

Comment: +1 Good posting: can I assume that if bring snacks / water in a small backpack I can check it into the cloakroom?  Given the security-posture: are small backpacks now prohibited?  Maybe this is a new question.

Comment: I never did that, I try to go light and never bring in a bag.

Comment: You can bring a small bag, size purse, with you into the museum and you can bring in some food, but you are not allowed to eat your own food while within the museum. I know as I ate a biscuit while in the museum, away from any art, the guard accepted my explanation of diabetics. There are several points to buy food and drinks in the museum but not all open early in the day, so make sure you locate one. You can always go (back) to the Pyramide entrance area where there is a place to sit and eat, which has very wide opening hours. I think you are also allowed to eat your own food there.